# Compare BOM Quantity on the Same Table with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the comparison Bill of Materials between 2 products in the same table. I have a `BOM` Table

[image]

I would like to compare quantity from

`PRODUCT A FROM ID=1` to  `PRODUCT CCC FROM ID=2`

`SUPPLIERPN` are unique for `(ID, PRODUCT)` combination

The expected result

[image]

My question: How can I get the expected result with SQL?

My SQL Server syntax knowledge to basic queries so I have no idea how to do this. I tried to search but I do not know the correct term to describe this type of problem.

Normally, I solved this type of problem in the application site (loaded all the data from Database Server then did the comparison).

Comment: How does `Qty Product A` of `3.00` work for SupplierPN of `777`? Your sample data doesn't match your desired results, or I'm missing something in the explanation of your logic.

Comment: @JNevill, sorry, I shifted the row by 1 - editing the picture

Comment: What happened to (2, CCC, 888)? Is that missing also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (CCC, 555) so the expected output of that product is incorrect. Honestly, if you can't do this manually and get the correct output you have a much bigger problem. Moreover, posting images is a terrible **TERRIBLE** way to provide information.

But here is one interpretation that attempts to correct all of your errors. It only occurred to me after writing it that your pn is a string and not numeric - which is why the literals used to populate the table variable do not have quote marks.

```
set nocount on;
declare @x table (salesid tinyint, product varchar(3), supplierpn varchar(5), qty decimal(5,2)); 
insert @x (salesid, product, supplierpn, qty) values
(1, 'A', 1234, 1), (1, 'A', 555, 2), (1, 'A', 666, 3), 
(1, 'BBB', 1234, 4), (1, 'BBB', 555, 5), 
(2, 'CCC', 1234, 6), (2, 'CCC', 666, 7), (2, 'CCC', 777, 8), (2, 'CCC', 888, 9) ; 
select * from @x order by salesid, product, qty;

with cte_a as (select supplierpn, qty from @x where salesid = 1 and product = 'A'), 
cte_ccc as (select supplierpn, qty from @x where salesid = 2 and product = 'CCC') 
select isnull(cte_a.supplierpn, cte_ccc.supplierpn) as supplierpn,
   cte_a.qty as qty_a, 
   cte_ccc.qty as qty_ccc, 
   isnull(cte_ccc.qty, 0) - isnull(cte_a.qty, 0) as delta 
from cte_a full join cte_ccc on cte_a.supplierpn = cte_ccc.supplierpn 
order by supplierpn;
```

Comment: My head was kind of spinning so I did not make it right 2nd edit.